# SourceKitService very high memory usage

Tags: xcode, sourcekitservice

I am using Xcode 9 and my SourceKitService using more than 5 GB memory. Due to it my system become very slower.

Every time, I have to force quite this service from activity monitor to come back to normal situation. A few minutes back this service appears again and start using my memory resources.

Any help about it.

Comment: Came here for just this reason. Started toying around with Swift and the default hello-world program generated by Xcode consumes 124MB. 124MB for white text and black background.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. AFAIK there's no workaround, other than kill the process.